# Do we have any documents that help to understand Ouroboros Praos?

Tags: ouroboros

I'm trying to understand how the Cardano election process work by reading the paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/573.pdf. Nevertheless, there are many mathematic formulas in the paper, I really find them difficult to understand them.

Does anyone know a summary document around Ouroboros Praos that could help to understand how it works easier?

Thank you!